# Getting response from lambda via callback and letting lambda continue working

Tags: aws-lambda

lets say I have this lambda function:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'longCheckout',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2) // pass params
  }, function(error, data) {

    console.log(error, data)
    callback(null, data);
  });
};
```

and I want to call the longCheckout lambda that will do some work and send back a response to the invoking lambda and then continue to execute a longer request. So the lambda function I am calling has a callback argument but when I call that passed in function, nothing happens in the invoking lambda. Here is what the lambda I am calling looks like

```js
exports.handler = (event, test, callback) => {
  docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    callback(....)
    // continue to execute 
  })
}
```

Comment: *"nothing happens in the invoking lambda"*  It isn't possible for *nothing* to happen.  An error, a timeout, *something* must be happening.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda can be invoked synchronously (the default behavior that you used), or asynchronously.
If you will choose to invoke asynchronously, both lambdas will continue running at the same time, but you won't be able to get any return value.

A possible solution to do what you ask for is:

1. Lambda 1 invokes synchronously Lambda 2
2. Lambda 2 calls `docClient.update` and invokes asynchronously Lambda 3 (then returns).
3. Lambda 3 makes the rest of the needed execution.

Read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) about asynchronous invocations.

Comment: Im having trouble calling a lambda asynchronously. It just doesn't get called

Comment: Just set 'InvocationType: Event' in the parameters when calling 'invoke' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)

Comment: i wasn't providing the callback and it wasn't running it at all. thanks